# Storage for code revisions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, storage

I have a Rails website where users can submit code to share with others. The users can update their submitted code, and other users can see not only the latest code but also the historical versions of that code.

Currently the code (current and historical) is stored in an InnoDB table. I'm concerned about the storage requirements with this, as every update a user increases the storage I need by the size of the code.

An average code submission is 25KB at the moment. I estimate that for every 100 reads of the latest code, there will be 1 read of a historical version and 1 code update. The data should compress well as an update would likely change only a small portion of the code.

I've been considering having the historical versions in a compressed storage option (an [ARCHIVE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html) or something on the filesystem?) while keeping the current code in the InnoDB table. Does this seem appropriate for my situation? Is there a better way?

Comment: sounds appropriate to me. If the user wants to view the history allow them to view it and query your history tables

Comment: Consider storing [deltas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).